# проблема с передачей файла на сервер

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь передать файл следующим способом:

```
       $('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(e) {
           var nm = this.value.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '')
           var datf = this.files[0];

           $.ajax({url: "sent.php", data: {'name': nm, 'file': datf}, processData: false, 
           contentType: false, type: 'POST', success: function(ev) { alarm(ev);
       }})})
```

В самом скрипте sent.php, если вывести весь массив `$GLOBALS`, то `$_FILES` и `$_POST` пусты. Что здесь не так?
P.S. Что-то есть в `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` - `string(15) "[object Object]"` Что там может быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю для передачи файлов через аякс надо бы использовать [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) и его методы, например [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) -  который  добавляет новое значение в существующий ключ внутри объекта FormData, или создает ключ, в случае если он отсутствует.

У метода `append` есть несколько параметров, которые принимает

- name - Имя поля, который будет содержать данные из value.
- value - Значение
- filename `Необязательный` - задает имя файла которое будет отправлено серверу

Т.е. если добавить файл так: `formData.append(nm , this.files[0]);`, то имя  файла будет совпадать с тем, которое заливали, а если так: `formData.append(nm , this.files[0], yoMySuperFileName);`, то у файла будет `[name] => yoMySuperFileName`

Отправка у вас будет выглядеть так:

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(e) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var nm = this.value.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '')                                 
    formData.append(nm , this.files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "get.php", 
        data: formData, 
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false, 
        type: 'POST', 
        success: function(ev) { 
            alarm(ev);  
        }
    })
})
```