# Передать данные file через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, submit

Как передать файл вместе с формой? передается все кроме файла...
Заранее спасибо большое!!!

```
<form id="InsetForm" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call() method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" value="" type="text">
<input id="LastName" name="LastName" value="" type="text">
<input id="ImageFile" name="ImageFile" accept=".jpg" type="file">

<input value="Send" type="submit">

</form>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function call() {
      var msg   = $('#InsetForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'Insert.php',
          data: msg,
          success: function(data) {alert(data);},
          error:  function(xhr, str){ alert('Возникла ошибка');
          }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: у Вас ошибка тут: `error:  function(xhr, str){ alert('Возникла ошибка);`

Comment: ок, но фйл не передается

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517304/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80/ ......... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516002/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80/ ....... смотрите эти вопросы.... там написано

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример с FormData [JSFIDDLE](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData)

[Подробней о FormData](http://jsfiddle.net/fmygzk7t/)

```
function setimage() {
  var $input = $("#uploadimage");
  var fd = new FormData;

fd.append('img', $input.prop('files')[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/script.php',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Зачем писать ответ, если это явно дубликат, который стоит закрыть.......эм..... как дубликат?