# xmlhttprequest загрузка файла на сервер

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно загружать и отправлять на сервер файл с помощью javascript? Если можно, подскажите, где прочитать об этом. Спасибо.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516021/191482 и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517351/191482 например

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress